# Recognising people from photos

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I have a large number (probably 10000) of personal photos taken over the last few years, a good proportion of which contain family members.

I'd like to put together a photo book of one family member, so I'd like to pull out the majority of photos containing them. 
Is there a way to do this in Mathematica? A pretrained neural net perhaps. Needs to be able to work on my laptop with 16Gb RAM and no usable GPU.

Comment: You may be able to do this just using `FacialFeatures` with `"Descriptor"` as the second argument and `FindFaces`. This will return a feature vector. Generate a mean feature vector from multiple images of your subject. From there you should be able to use `FindFaces` on each image, and then compare the distance of each face's `"Descriptor"` from the mean of your subject. If the distance is small enough, it's probably the same person.

Comment: If you can supply a sample dataset (not necessarily your photos) that would be helpful.